# Trim whitespace using eloquent?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to trim all existing titles in a database column.

```
DB::table('books')
    ->update([
        'title' => DB::raw(TRIM('title'))
    ]);
```

But the above has no effect on each column's left and right whitespace. Where am I going wrong?

Please note I'm using MySQL `TRIM`.

Comment: you have wriiten trim as capital letters but php has trim() function, is it a mistake while writing here or in your original code as well

Comment: if you are using  trim in eloquent then shouldn't be it like `DB::raw("TRIM(title)")`

Comment: I'm using mysql trim

Comment: @panthro No you are not using the mysql `trim` function in your provided code, you are using PHP's `trim` function and even if you use the mysql `trim` function it won't work because you don't have access to column values when doing mass updates with the query builder. One option would be to loop through every book and then trim and update its title.